# ¿Como puedo obtener el valor maximo y minimo de un registro en algolia?

Tags: php, sql

Estoy usando la api de algolia para hacer una busqueda de productos, donde $value es lo busca el cliente.

$results = $index->search($value);

En el registro de productos por ejemplo tengo los campos: nombre, precio, stock, etc
Quiero saber si hay alguna manera de que me arroje el valor maximo y minimo entre todos los productos buscados, asi como en mysql donde puedo usar MIN(precio) y MAX(precio) en una tabla

Comment: Hola. Tu pregunta no es clara. ¿Has leído la documentación de la API para saber si lo que quieres hacer se puede? ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué problemas o errores tienes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya lo solucione
intentaba de todo y muchas veces lo principal que era poner las facetas en el codigo como esto
$results = $index->search($search_value, [ 'facets' => [ "price"] ]);
pero el problema es que aparte de poner facetas en el codigo php tambien debia poner facetas en la configuracion del administrador en mi indice